# Text selection style

Tags: android, text, input, selection, css-selectors

Is it possible to change text selector (selection, cursor, etc.) color or style for my android application somehow (like for one in the link below)?

[Selection image example](http://developer.android.com/design/media/text_input_textselection.png)

Or it is default for device and can not be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody need it, I've figured out that to change selection color the following style:

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/my_color</item>
```

Comment: Does anybody know if it is possible to set a custom shape for the highlighting? Besides the color change, I have to add a corner radius to fulfill the rounded rect design created by the design agency... :‑/